# Bootstrapping to Overcome Power Concern with ANOVA?

Tags: anova, bootstrap, statistical-power, effect-size

all,

I just conducted the power analysis for a lab study I am hoping to run soon. The main idea is comparing the difference in means across three conditions with a balanced one-way ANOVA (see image below).

Basically, I am amazed at how underpowered I am with moderate effect sizes. Unless I set large effect sizes (f=0.4), I am severely underpowered.

To help overcome these power issues, **I'm wondering if bootstrapping may be an appropriate method of resampling?** While I recognize the lab study participants are not nationally representative of the broader public, I'm more interested in the psychological phenomenon that occurs.

***What do you all think--would bootstrapping be one method of
overcoming this potential issue with power? Open to any and all suggestions!***

**

[image]

Comment: No, bootstrapping will not in general improve power. Not answering formally as there have been previous discussions [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398491/), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112147/), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/209474/). If you really cannot collect more data, I can recommend the book [Small Sample Size Solutions (2020)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398491/), which notably does not include a chapter on the bootstrap (because it's not a good small sample technique).

Comment: Thank you! I tried looking for an answer in other places but couldn't find one. Much appreciated.